# JavaScript Order List Processing

Tags: javascript

Takes 3 Arguments: an order list OrderList; a Number OrderId; & a String State that is either "Processing" or "Delivered". OrderList is an array of order objects.

Updates The order List Depending on the state and returns the Updated List.

-> If the state is "Processing", It updates the object in the list Having id as OrderId, to have the state "Processing".

-> If the state is "Delivered", It Deletes the object from the list having the id of orderId.

If there is no order with the given orderId then the Function returns the list orderList unchanged.

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
let inputString = "";
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on("data", function(chunk) {
  inputString += chunk;
});
process.stdin.on("end", function() {
  inputString = inputString.split('\n');
  main();
});

function readLine() {
  return inputString[currentLine++];
}


function processOrderList(orderList, orderId, state) {
  // Write your code here
  console.log(orderId);
  console.log(orderList);
  console.log(state);

}


function main() {
  const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

  const orderCount = parseInt(readLine().trim());
  let orderList = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < orderCount; i++) {
    orderList.push({
      id: i + 1,
      state: 'Received'
    })
  };

  let numberOfOperations = parseInt(readLine().trim());
  let updatedOrderList = [...orderList];
  while (numberOfOperations-- > 0) {
    const inputs = readLine().trim().split(' ');
    const orderId = parseInt(inputs[0]);
    const updatedState = inputs[1];

    updatedOrderList = processOrderList(updatedOrderList, orderId, updatedState);
    updatedOrderList = [...updatedOrderList];
  }

  if (updatedOrderList.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < updatedOrderList.length; i++) {
      const order = updatedOrderList[i];
      ws.write(`Order with id ${order.id} is in ${order.state} state\n`);
    };
  } else {
    ws.write(`All orders are in Delivered state\n`);
  }

  ws.end();
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5):

This will be fine

```
function processOrderList(orderList, orderId, state) {
  // Write your code here
  return state === 'Processing' ?
      orderList.map(item => ({
          ...item,
          state: item.id === orderId ? 'Processing' : item.state
      })) :
      orderList.filter(item => item.id !== orderId);
}
```